# Outline path of a image/silhouette in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game in Xcode/Swift for iPad/iPhone.

What I need to do is to get the outline path of an image/silhouette, so that I can animate along the outline of the image/silhouette. This to create a laser cutting like effect, the one you see in movies when they break through a door/window with a lasercutter.

Just drawing it as a Beizer path won't work since I need to do this for a bunch of images/silhouettes. If possible I would prefer just to add images to my project and do the outlining in code, that way I can easily expand with more shapes and sizes.

In SpriteKit I've tried to use a SKPhysicsBody and then use the Alpha to create the outline. This gives me that outline but not as a path, so I can't animate along that line. 
Actually when enabling ".showsPhysics" I get the line I need, but still not a line I can use for animations.

Is there a way to get to use/modify the ".showsPhysics" method or to reverse the PhysicsBody to a path?

I'm coding in Swift, and any advice would be appreciated.

This is an example of what I need, I need the blue line as a path for animation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit has a method to create a physics body from the contents of a texture. Read [bodyWithTexture:size:](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithTexture:size:) for more information, especially the Discussion session. You should consider the balance between the performance and the accuracy.

Given an image below, here's a simple example to use `bodyWithTexture:size:`,

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "rex")
let rex = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "rex")
rex.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
rex.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
rex.physicsBody?.dynamic = false    // This line is just for demo
self.addChild(rex)
```

**Image:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi WangYudong, 
thanks for your answer but this I'm already familiar with. What I'm looking for is someway to get the path of the outline, like with a Bezier path so that I can animate along that path.  

So to specify, I need to create a path that follows the outline of an image. Like with the texture of a physics body but as a path.

Comment: @ChrissyMcBeal Sorry for the late response. I don't know if getting the path from a physics body is possible, but I'd like to know more about _I can animate along that path_, maybe we can find another way to do that.